# Yii 1 running inside Yii 2

Tags: yii, yii2

I have a requirement to develop a REST api for a Yii 1.1 app using Yii 2. Yii 2 will be the front app which will handle the request and then use Yii 1.1 app for processing/information retrieval.

[The example provided in the Yii 2 Guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-yii-integration.html#using-both-yii2-yii1) is having Yii 2 app running inside Yii 1 where Yii 1 will be the front app receiving the requests.

My requirement is the other way round.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why was this down voted? I have spent enough hours in research and also the official forum has no answers yet as well. Please remove the down vote or explain more.

Comment: Do you really need to build one application? Your scenario sound as if there is a clear separation of concerns. Why not use split up in two seperate framework instances, one with Yii and one with Yii2 which talk to each other via REST APIs? They don't interfere at all and you can use full set of Yii2 features while preserving your old Yii application.

Comment: The question was if Yii1 can be configured to run inside Yii2, just like how the guide has Yii2 running inside Yii1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a project to do exactly what you are doing: https://github.com/yiiext/yii2-yii-bridge

That said, I'd recommend WeSee's comment above and think about separating the apps completely and use an API to interface.

Comment: Perfect, I will check it out. The reason I do not want to do two separate apps is because, there is no business layer for yii2. It is just an REST API for the old yii app and will slowly help us migrate to yii2.

Comment: I checked it out and it works, but it seems that the extension is not actively developed, so it supports only some basic configs.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the module feature of yii2, you can convert your yii1 project as a module inside the yii2 application.